# How to insert an element into a nested dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary that I want to use to describe data that changes with time. I want to then create an outer dictionary that has time increments as the keys and the previously mentioned dictionary as the value.

However, when I try to change one element in the nested dictionary in a given time step all of the time steps with the same dictionary key are changed as well.

I would like to have the same keys for the inner dictionaries but be able to insert unique values for the different time steps.

Any ideas why this is occurring?

```
time = 3

inner_dict = dict([(i,[]) for i in ['a','b','c']])

outer_dict= dict([(time_step,inner_dict) for time_step in range(time)])

test[1]['a'] = 20

print(test[2]['a'])
```

`test[2]['a']` should still be an empty list. Or at least that's what I want to achieve.

Comment: The inner dict is literally the same for each time step.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are passing reference to the same mutable `inner_dict` to each time step in the outer dictionary. You need to create a separate instance of inner dict for each time step. Try doing something like this:

```
outer = dict([(time_step, {i:[] for i in ['a', 'b', 'c']}) for time_step in range(time)])
```

Or simply in dict comprehension

```
outer = {timestep: {i:[] for i in ['a', 'b', 'c']} for timestep in range(time)}
```